# Qt Cannot find libs

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I want to start learning QT. I am using Ubuntu, so I installed QT from the software center and I created an HTML5 project and I tried to make it run but I got a lot of errors so I did the following that solved some of them:

```
sudo apt-get install qtquick1-5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

but still am getting this now :

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lgio-2.0
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstapp-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstinterfaces-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstpbutils-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstvideo-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstbase-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
:-1: error: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
:-1: error: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
:-1: error: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
:-1: error: cannot find -lglib-2.0
:-1: error: cannot find -lsqlite3
```

So what should I do, and how can I install all the missing libs ?

Comment: Did you added those libraries on your path? or in the -L param?
If you have those libraries on an different place than /usr/lib you should put -L/Your/Libraries/Place

Comment: Can you show your .pro file?

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same problem on Debian/jessie.
for example the missing gmodule, i try :

```
$locate libgmodule
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0.3600.4
```

the compilation command line must contains "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu".
The solution is to create a symlink :

```
$cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$sudo ln -s libgmodule-2.0.so.0 libgmodule-2.0.so
```

do the same for all missing libraries.
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the software center of Ubuntu and install all the packages one by one.These all are dependencies for installing Qt. 
Like search for sqlite3 and install.Like this do for all.
libglib etc etc

Comment: but the problem is that the names are not the same in the software center , such as i cant find libgstapp-0.10 or libgstapp , i found somthing called libgst but is it the same ?

Comment: i tried it and am still getting the same errors , i installed the libgio and the libgst and still everything is the same

Comment: you are missing something..I will suggest better go to Qt website and install Qt from source rather then from Software center.

Comment: i tried but it installed a .run file i dont know how to use it and i was reading online that its recommended to install it from the software center